# Cropping a grid of polygons to a single polygon gives an odd result

Tags: intersection, vector-grid, clip

I am trying to create a grid over a polygon from which I can choose a random subset of cells for sampling. The problem occurs when I crop the grid, which I am converting to polygons, by the polygon shapefile. For some reason this results in a polygon the shape of the cropping polygon but with lines across it. After opening the resulting shapefile in QGIS I can see that the lines are "edges" of the polygon, because when I get rid of the outline of the polygon, the lines go away.

Can you explain what error, if any, I am making, or do you have an alternate means of generating a grid over a polygon from which a subset of grid cells can be selected (and ideally turned in a shapefile)?

Here is some sample code:

(California boundary found at https://data.ca.gov/dataset/ca-geographic-boundaries)

```
require(rgdal)
require(sp)
require(raster)
require(rgeos)

# Load shapefile
ca <- readOGR(dsn = "...", layer = "CA_State_TIGER2016")
ca.utm <- spTransform(ca, CRSobj = "+proj=utm +zone=11 ellps=WGS84")

# Calculate number of grid cells necessary
x.cells <- ceiling((ca.utm@bbox[1,2]-ca.utm@bbox[1,1])/10000)
y.cells <- ceiling((ca.utm@bbox[2,2]-ca.utm@bbox[2,1])/10000)

# Generate grid
ca.grid <- raster(extent(ca.utm), nrow=y.cells, 
                      ncol=x.cells, crs=ca.utm@proj4string)
ca.grid.poly <- as(as(ca.grid, "SpatialPixels"),"SpatialPolygons")
ca.grid.utm <- spTransform(ca.grid.poly, CRSobj = "+proj=utm +zone=11 ellps=WGS84")

# Crop grid to polygon
ca.grid.inter <- gIntersection(ca.grid.utm, ca.utm)
# or
ca.grid.crop <- crop(ca.grid.utm, ca.utm)

# both gIntersection and crop give same result as far as I can tell
```

Here is a screen shot:

```
plot(ca.grid.inter)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Or a link to one, if you don't have the reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the cropping step. Change

```
ca.grid.inter <- gIntersection(ca.grid.utm, ca.utm)
```

to

```
ca.grid.inter <- gIntersection(ca.grid.utm, ca.utm, byid = TRUE)
```

I'm not sure why not including `byid = True` produces the odd result that it does, but adding definitely solves the problem.